# Who is Kagura from Boruto?

Tags: naruto, boruto

In episode 26 of *Boruto*, we saw a new character named Kagura. He looks like Yagura so much.

[image: kagura and yagura]

Are they related?

Comment: I removed asking for theories because this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. We're trying to achieve the most official/objective answer that can be backed up by references.

Comment: Kagura karatachi is yagura karatachi's grandson.

Comment: Do you have a source for that claim?

Comment: It is mentioned in one of the mist village arc episodes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kagura Karatachi is a shinobi of Kirigakure, who works as an aide to the Sixth Mizukage. He is in line to become one of the seven swordsmen of the mist.

> He looks like Yagura so much. Are they related?

Yes, Kagura is Yagura's grandson. Tsurushi Hachiya said so in episode 27 of the Boruto anime as he also mentioned that when Kagura drew his sword he became a different person and killed his classmates which Kagura obviously regrets.